# Having to dynamically change the state : how to avoid an infinite-loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component which receives data from a parent.
Now, this data is dynamic and I do not know beforehand what the properties are called exactly.
I need to render them in a certain fashion and that all works perfectly fine.
Now though, these dynamic objects have a property which is a number, which has to be displayed in my component.
To do so, I thought while iterating over the data, I will add the values to the `sum`, which is to be displayed. Whenever one of the data object changes, the `sum` will change, too (since I am using `useState` and React will detect that change.
But that exactly is the problem I don't know how to solve.
It is obvious that right now my code generates an infinite-loop:

1. The component is created and rendered for the first time.
2. During this process, `setSum()` is called, and therefore changing the state.
3. React detects that and orders a re-rendering.

So how do I fix this? I feel like I am missing something quite obvious here, but I am too invested to see it.

I have tried to boil down my code to the most easy to read code snippet which focuses on the problem only. Any suggestions to improve the readabilty are welcome!

```
const ComponentA = (data) => {
  const [sum, setSum] = React.useState(0);

    const renderData = (dataToRender) => {
      //Here lies the problem already
      setSum(0)
      const result = [];
      dataToRender.forEach((objData, index) => {
        result.push(<JSX Item>Content</JSX Item>);
        //and some more stuff, not relevant

        // will not get this far
        const newSum = sum+objData.propertyAmount;
        setSum(newSum);

      });
    return result;
    };

  return(
  //...someJSXElements
  {data.relevantObjectArray && renderData(data.relevantObjectArray)}
  <div>{sum}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's re-rendering infinitely is because you are setting the state every time the component is rendered, which subsequently triggers another re-render. What you need to do is separate your display code from your state-setting code. I initially thought that `useEffect` would be a good solution (you can see the edit history for my original answer), however from the React docs:

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or **when the next state depends on the previous one**. [(React docs)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

So you could therefore try something like this:

```js
const reducer = (sum, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return sum + action.propertyAmount;
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const initialSum = 0;

const ComponentA = (data) => {
  const [sum, sumReducer] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialSum);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    data.relevantObjectArray.forEach((objData, index) => {
      sumReducer({ type: "increment", propertyAmount: objData.propertyAmount });
    });
  }, [data.relevantObjectArray]);

  const renderData = (dataToRender) => {
    const result = [];
    dataToRender.forEach((objData, index) => {
      result.push(<div>Content</div>);
    });
    return result;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data.relevantObjectArray && renderData(data.relevantObjectArray)}
      <div>{sum}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Example on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-i4491?file=/index.js).

Answer (score 1):

```
const ComponentA = (data) => {
  const [sum, setSum] = React.useState(0);

    const renderData = (dataToRender) => {
      //Here lies the problem already
      setSum(0)
      const result = [];
      dataToRender.forEach((objData, index) => {
        result.push(<JSX Item>Content</JSX Item>);
        //and some more stuff, not relevant

        // will not get this far
        const newSum = sum+objData.propertyAmount;
        setSum(newSum);

      });
    return result;
    };

React.useEffect(() => {
renderData();
return () => {
console.log('UseEffect cleanup')});
}, [data);


  return(
  //...someJSXElements
//The line below is causing the continuos re-render because you keep calling the function (renderData)

  //{data.relevantObjectArray && renderData(data.relevantObjectArray)}

  <div>{sum}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation as to what your code does and why your solution works.